# Loading a partial view into a Div AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm relatively new to angular and mostly just toying around with a simple SPA, most of my experience comes from VS and MVC 5, so I know something like this can be done with partial views. But I can't seem to figure it out with angular.

In this plunkr, I have an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/H4yyrNvWlTiSoahYHVXA?p=preview

Basically, I would like the dynamic list of links to point to a different view, for now I just have home.

However I can't even seem to get the view to load when hardcoded.

I think I should be using ng-include:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-include ng-src="Home.html">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend you use `ng-include` for this kind of logic.  The [Angular Router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), the [Angular New Router](https://github.com/angular/router), and [ui-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) all have this functionality, and have many features built in.

However, to address your concern with this specific code snippet, `ng-include` expects a value to be passed to it. The value passed should be a model property that evaluates to a string, or a string constant.  In the case of a string constant, it should be included in a single quote `'`. So, try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" data-ng-include="'home.html'" >
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense, checking out the route options now. Both examples worked. Marking yours as answer because of the route examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the template url in ng-include directive, and if it's constant (e.g. home.html), need to put it in single quote:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" data-ng-include="'home.html'" >
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can put the template url in controller scope variable and bind it to ng-include

Comment: how to do this using javascript instead defining in html?